# physics : inflate a mesh until it reaches the limits of its container

Tags: physics, 3d-printing, photogrammetry

I have a room scanned from a photogrammetry.

I would like to grow a mesh (like a baloon inflating) inside this room until it reaches the room boundaries.

The goal is to have a mesh that would be the "negative space" of the original photogrammety, and then to print that mesh.

Would this be possible ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://forums.sketchup.com/t/need-to-create-an-inverse-or-shell-of-a-3d-surface/15405/8
and 
https://global.discourse-cdn.com/sketchup/original/2X/9/9ed109b7878d12affd07c13727e2623bae42fe8a.gif

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72612/how-to-turn-a-mesh-inside-out-like-a-sock